# display results of jquery in a label in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

I want to display result of this javascript in a label control on my asp.net page, instead of alert. how can i do so?

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- Require EasyJQuery After JQuery --><script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript" src="http://api.easyjquery.com/easyjquery.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">
    // 1. Your Data Here
    function my_callback(json) {
        alert("IP :" + json.IP + " COUNTRY: " + json.COUNTRY);
    }

    function my_callback2(json) {

       alert("IP :" + json.IP + " COUNTRY: " + json.COUNTRY + " City: " + json.cityName + " Region Name: " + json.regionName);
    }

    // 2. Setup Callback Function
   // EasyjQuery_Get_IP("my_callback"); // fastest version
    EasyjQuery_Get_IP("my_callback2","full"); // full version
</script>
```

Comment: What is the id of your label.

Comment: Do you want to call the javascript function from code behind

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Using Dynamic ID

The label control of asp.net is rendered by default as `span` So you can set the text inside by find this control by ID, and type inside using the `text` as:

```
  $('#<%=txtLabel.ClientID%>').text("message");
```

### Using Static ID

alternative (ver 4+) you can set `ClientIDMode="Static"` on your control so the id not change

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="txtName" ClientIDMode="Static">Test</asp:Label>
```

render as `<span id="txtName">Test</span>` and write inside him as

```
$('#txtName').text("message");
```

Your function will then be

```
function my_callback(json) {
    $('#txtName').text("IP :" + json.IP + " COUNTRY: " + json.COUNTRY);
}

function my_callback2(json) {
   $('#txtName').text("IP :" + json.IP + " COUNTRY: " + json.COUNTRY + " City: " + json.cityName + " Region Name: " + json.regionName);
}
```

Comment: But the question seems to be confusing , I think he also wants to call his javascript function from code behind.

Comment: @freebird I try to think that... hmm not see it, only won to display the message on the page.

Comment: I want to run javascript whixh fetches me ip adress n location, want to display the same in label

Comment: @Zoya What part is not working because I have type 2 different methods here (and they working because I have test them)

Comment: 0k , could u please send me both methods seperately , well m using asp.net 4.0

Comment: @Zoya see the answer again, is more clear. Use the first code line

Comment: @Aristos , sorry m so confused....   do i do this? define label in form                                                           <asp:Label runat="server" ID="txtName" ClientIDMode="Static">Test</asp:Label>    & code                                         function my_callback(json) {
    $('#txtName').text("IP :" + json.IP + " COUNTRY: " + json.COUNTRY);
}

Comment: @Zoya Yes you can do that. Just Be sure that the txtName is unique (not exist again in the page).

Comment: @Aristos not working, i m using asp.net 3.5 may be... can u please gimme a complete code, n did it work when u tried? I really need it to work, my client is asking.....

Comment: @Zoya Sorry to sound bad, but this is not my role, I am not here to debug and fully solve all your issue on your page, and this is complete code on your question that is work, and what your client have to do with me ? is not pay me, is pay you - do not mentioned as argument to me. Really I do not know your fully page and what detail make it not work.

Comment: @Aristos m sorry, check my answer m half way through http://stackoverflow.com/a/11062181/1445836

Answer (score 1):

When you use server side controls their Client ID changes.As Aristos correctly pointed out ,if you are using (v4+) you can set the `ClientIDMode` property to `static` so that its ID remains the same.
If the ID of your label is myLabel and you set `ClientIDMode=static` ,then the ID of the label will be myLabel itself.
Otherwise the ID is rendered something like this `#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_myLabel`.
This should do  the trick for you.

```
$('#<%= myLabel.ClientID %>').text("set whatever you need");
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: @Aristos May be ,but I know the question now , what we are trying to suggest him is correct.He just wants to set the value of his Label control using jquery.

Comment: @Aristos Got it , will take care of that from nex time.

Comment: @Aristos What exactly should I re-format , can you point me something.

Comment: @Aristos Is that a bit more convincing.

Comment: see I want label on my page to have the value what alert is returning in javascript function, basically i want my website users to get their city, country name on the pages like google has.

Comment: @Zoya Then you have to first find the id of the label using javascript , and then use that id.

Answer (score 0):

```
head runat="server">
    <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>





<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://api.easyjquery.com/easyjquery.js"></script>

<script language=Javascript>
    function setup_ip(json) {
        var htmlx = " Your IP Address: <b>" + json.IP;
        htmlx += "</b> | Country: " + json.countryName;
        if (json.cityName != "Unknown" || json.regionName != "Unknown") {
            htmlx += " | City: " + json.cityName + " / " + json.regionName;
        } else {
            htmlx += " | Your Time: " + json.localTimeZone;
        }

        $("#myipx").html(htmlx);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {


        EasyjQuery_Get_IP("setup_ip", "full");

    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <div class="inner">
<p class="welcome-message">
<a href="http://www.easyjquery.com/detect-get-clients-ip-address-country-using-javascript-php/"id="topid" title="Javascript, PHP jQuery API Detect Clients IP Address and Country - Geo Location"   ><asp:Label ID="myipx" runat="server"  ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label>Detecting Clients IP Address - Country - City</span></a>
<br />
<asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server"  ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label>
                </p>



            <!-- END #footer-texture -->
            </div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: m half way through , now can i get value of label in .cs file

Comment: Do you have buy this functionality ? `EasyjQuery_Get_IP`

Comment: nope, I dont wanna buy, I have now fetched it in the label, but as u said it renders as span... i get its null value in .cs file.. and thans a lot for ur support... have been to Athens this May, beautiful!

Comment: I think that you can find it for free also - but - to make it work you need to first run a function on the code behind that set some cookies, then this function works.

Comment: I have finally found the key... it works check http://stackoverflow.com/a/11078196/1445836 thanks a ton to u too, vote up my answer!

Answer (score -1):

Find the ID or name of your label and set its text like this:

```
$('label#myLabel').text('foo');
```

Comment: even though its correct the way you write it, its a general answer and the first problem is, how to find how the id is written from asp.net on html - and if this is possible, because there are controls that not included by any tag.