# Access javascript variable's value in .cs file that is in in code behind?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, json, c#

I want to access java script's return value , which in is in a variable and a label, i want to use it in .cs file, how do i do that? I have fetch the out put of javascript in a variable and also a label control of asp.net...  I get the values both the ways, but in need it .cs file to save it in my data bsae, help me please.. Thank u

```
<script language=Javascript>
    function setup_ip(json) {
        var htmlx = " Your IP Address: <b>" + json.IP;
        htmlx += "</b> | Country: " + json.countryName;
        if (json.cityName != "Unknown" || json.regionName != "Unknown") {
            htmlx += " | City: " + json.cityName + " / " + json.regionName;
            var s = " | City: " + json.cityName + " / " + json.regionName;
        } else {
            htmlx += " | Your Time: " + json.localTimeZone;
        }

        $("#myipx").html(htmlx);
     //   $('#<%= lbl1.ClientID %>').text(htmlx);
        $('#<%= lbl1.ClientID %>').text(s);

       // var txtCountry = document.getElementById('<%=lbl1.ClientID %>');        

    }

    $(document).ready(function() {


        EasyjQuery_Get_IP("setup_ip", "full");

    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <div class="inner">
<p class="welcome-message">
<a href="http://www.easyjquery.com/detect-get-clients-ip-address-country-using-javascript-php/"id="topid" title="Javascript, PHP jQuery API Detect Clients IP Address and Country - Geo Location"   >
<asp:Label ID="myipx" runat="server"  ClientIDMode="Static"></a></asp:Label>Detecting Clients IP Address - Country - City</span>
<br />
<asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server"  ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label>
                </p>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtCountry" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>


            <!-- END #footer-texture -->
            </div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: For final answer, I have put up below http://stackoverflow.com/a/11078196/1445836

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use this values you have following options :

1.)As label is your server side control you can easily access label text value in .cs file so main issue with javascript variable here you can assign this value to asp:hidden field so you can also access this in .cs file like :

```
<script language=Javascript>
function setup_ip(json) {

$("#hdn").val('your javascript variable');
}
</script>
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" ScriptMode="Release">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpnlHidden" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <input runat="server" type="hidden" id="hdn" value="0" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

cs file :

```
  string str = hdn.value//Where ever you want to store value
```

2.)Another option you can use pagemethod here and pass both values as parameter to .cs file.

javascript :

```
  PageMethods.getValue(parameter1,parameter2, OnSucceeded, OnFailed);
function OnSucceededID(result, methodName)
{
   //get result back if you want after successfully execution of pagemethod on server side  
}

 function OnFailedID(error, methodName) {
        if (error !== null) {
           alert(error.get_message());
        }
    }
```

CS file :

```
   [WebMethod(enableSession: true)]
    public static returntype getValue(parameter type parameter1,parameter type parameter2)
    {
        do what you want to do with these values.

    }
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: <script language=Javascript>
function setup_ip(json) {

$("#hdn").val('your javascript variable');
}
</script>  but hdn.Value is NULL....:(

Comment: where you are try to use this value?I mean have you fired any postback event before calling this ?Now check updated answer.Try this it works for you

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12673/discussion-between-sunny-and-zoya)

Answer (score 2):

To send client-side information (the JavaScript result/variable) to the server, you must...send the information to the server. :-) You can do that in a variety of ways, the two best for updating a database would be:

- [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) - A means of sending data from the client to the server without page refresh
- Form submission - A standard form submission

Answer (score 2):

Create a server side hidden field, Place javascript value in it. and read value form  hidden field on server side.

Html

```
<input type="hidden" id="myhidden" runat="server">
```

Access in javascript

```
 document.getElementById("myhidden").value="jsvalue";
```

Access in code behind

```
myhidden.Value
```

OR

you can use ajax to send data to the server.

Comment: var s;  document.getElementById("hid").value = s;     <asp:HiddenField ID ="hid" runat="server" />  ok???? string b,c;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        c = hid.Value;

Comment: okay, now how do i access it in .cs file as now, string c= hid.value; doesnt work

Comment: string c= hid.Value;  V is capital

Answer (score 2):

This is the javascript and aspx page

```
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://api.easyjquery.com/easyjquery.js"></script>

<script language=Javascript>
    function setup_ip(json) {
        var htmlx = " Your IP Address: <b>" + json.IP;
        htmlx += "</b> | Country: " + json.countryName;
        var s = " | City: " + json.cityName + " / " + json.regionName;


      $("#hdn").val(s);


        if (json.cityName != "Unknown" || json.regionName != "Unknown") {
            htmlx += " | City: " + json.cityName + " / " + json.regionName;

           s = " | City: " + json.cityName + " / " + json.regionName;
        } else {
            htmlx += " | Your Time: " + json.localTimeZone;
        }




    }

    $(document).ready(function() {


        EasyjQuery_Get_IP("setup_ip", "full");

    });



function testValue() {
    $('#hdn').val();
}
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" ScriptMode="Release">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpnlHidden" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <input runat="server" type="hidden" id="hdn" value="0" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
    <div class="inner">
<p class="welcome-message">
<a ><href="http://www.easyjquery.com/detect-get-clients-ip-address-country-using-javascript-php/"id="topid" title="Javascript, PHP jQuery API Detect Clients IP Address and Country - Geo Location"   ></a>

                <asp:TextBox ID="loc" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                </p>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="setup_ip(json);" onclick="Button1_Click" />

            </div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

this is .cs  code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        loc.Text = hdn.Value;
    }


  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
string str = hdn.Value; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can post data to the server using an ajax request. This is fairly straightforward since you are already using jquery. See api ref http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Page.aspx/method_name",
    data: { name: "some data", id: "some more data" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

For this example, in your code-behind for Page.aspx you would have a method named method_name, which takes two parameters: string name, string id. That method would be decorated with the `[WebMethod]` attribute. Then you can use these however you like in that method.